# How to know where Word VBA 'Find' has found something

Tags: vba, ms-word, find, range

In the While loop below, I need to create a Range object whose Start and End properties indicate the current instance of "whatever", so that I can pass it to a certain routine.

This information isn't in the Start and End properties of ActiveDocument.Range, and I haven't identified it in the Find object. Where should I be looking?

```
    Sub FindWhatever()
      With ActiveDocument.Range
        With .Find
          .Wrap = wdFindStop
          .Text = "whatever"
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute = True
          '??? Create a Range object indicating this instance of "whatever" ???
          'Pass this Range object to a certain routine
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
      End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: lookup .duplicate on the range object

Comment: When used on a `Range` object `Find` redefines the range to the range of the match. See documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find

Answer (score 1):

The `Range` object is redefined after locating the matching range. More detail on

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Find object (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

*Option 1:*

```
Sub FindWhatever()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With Rng
        With .Find
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Text = "whatever"
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            ' Rng is the object of search result
            Rng.Select ' for testing
            Stop ' for testing
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

---

*Option 2:*

```
Sub FindWhatever()
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection
        With .Find
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Text = "whatever"
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            ' Selection is the object of search result
            Selection.Select ' for testing
            Stop ' for testing
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```